# Difference between "multe" and "iomege"?

Tags: word-meaning, word-formation

So, I learned the word "iomete" and when reading I saw that "iomege" also exists. Not sure exactly what the difference between that and "multe" is however. Also, between "malmulte" and "iomete"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correlative, *tabelvorto*, *iom* means "some undefined amount". From that you can construct a word *iomete*, "some undefined small amount" + *e-finaĵo*. Words with the *e-finaĵo* are usually said to be adverbs, and that's fine as long as you remember, that in Esperanto adverbs have a wider use than in English.

Anyway a typical use for *iomete* is a phrase like:

- *Mi komprenas Esperanton nur iomete* : I understand Esperanto only a little.

I have never seen *iomege*, "some undefined big amount" + *e-finaĵo*, but of course that doesn't mean there couldn't be use for it.

*Multe* is the adverbial form of the adjective *multa*, "many". Both *multa* and *multe* pretty much requires that it somehow known "many of what". *Malmulte* is on the opposite end of the scale, "a little/(a) few".

- *Mi ne dormis multe* : I didn't sleep a lot.
- *Ĝi flugis multe antaŭ ĉiuj aliaj* : It flew a lot in front of all others.
- *Pli bone malmulte gajni ol multe perdi* : Better to get a little than loose a lot.

For a more detailed answer, please, provide more context, whole sentences, where you saw those words.

Comment: **[iomege](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iomege)**: quite a bit; a lot; very much. Ex: _Ho jes, ŝi ja aktivas ekonomie! Eĉ **iomege** tro. -- Oh yes, she's active economically! Even **quite a bit** too active_.

Comment: @Vidamuzo, I was trying to say that I haven't come across with _iomege_. I just googled for it and got quite a low number of hits, so the word is rarely used.

Comment: I agree; _iomege_ is rarely used and doesn't even appear in PIV or ReVo. Only 5 hits in Tekstaro. I was surprised to find a definition for it in Wiktionary and just wanted to add that information to your answer.

Comment: I see, so would it be incorrect to say _Mi multe komprenas Esperanto._ or _Mi komprenas Esperanto nur malmulte._? Also, a mostly unrelated question, where do adverbs go :D (I thought they had to be next to the verb but with your example with _nur iomete_ it's not).

Comment: You thought correctly. The normal position is just before the verb they modify (and this connection is stronger than in many other languages). I have no definite answer, but I seem to have noticed that the adverb is put into the end, if it modifies the whole phrase (see the examples above). Ofc this leaves room for interpretations.

Answer (score 0):

```
iom:  nedifinita, sed plej ofte malgranda kvanto aŭ nombro

-eg-: plej alta grado de grandeco aŭ intenseco, rilate al la radiko
```

La kunmeto de tiuj du estas ja *ebla* sed ne klara (same kiel, ni diru, **dolĉegeta** aŭ **multegete**) . Mi ĝin neniam renkontis kaj *mi* ne bone komprenas ĉu la rezulta grado/kvanto estas entute granda aŭ eta.

Do, por via unua demando, unu diferenco estas ĉefe la netuja analizeblo de **iomege**.

Via dua demando rilatas pli normalajn, uzatajn vortojn. **Malmulte** kaj **iom** estas preskaŭ samsignifaj (memoru ke **iom** jam rilatas etan gradon/kvanton), **iomete** estus pli simila al **malmultete**.

Imagu ke ni du manĝas malsamajn glaciaĵojn kaj mi volas gustumi la vian.

```
Mi: ĉu vi donu iomete por gustumi?
Vi: jes (kaj vi donas al mi etetetan kvanton)
Mi: (plendante) tio estas tre malmulte, guston mi ne sentos!
```

Mi uzis **iom-** por la peto kaj **malmulte** por la plendo, sed la signifo estas tre simila. Tio okazas en ĉiuj vivantaj lingvoj, la fakta uzo decidas la signifon kaj nuancoj aperas, kaj kelkfoje stabiliĝas, tiel.

Ekzemple, estas malfacile trovi universalan *vortaran* malsamon inter **eta** kaj **malgranda**, sed se vi demandas al unuopaj parolantoj vi trovos ke kelkfoje ili *sentas* nuancon kaj verŝajne ĉiam scias kiun el la du ebloj uzi, depende de la kuntektso.